Does "until" imply an end date? Child support question
My child support provision in my divorce decree states:  "Child support will continue until child turns age 18 or graduates high school.  Whichever is later."
Does this mean that it unequivocally ends at the later of those two dates?
I have two statutes that appear to contradict. 452.340 subsection 5 states in essence, if they are enrolled in secondary school support continues until 21. However, 452.370 subsection 4 states support is terminated at emancipation unless agreed to in writing or expressly provided in the decree. My decree provides the statement in my question, "Child support continues until age 18 or high school graduation. Whichever is later." My confusion is if that statement is enough to terminate at 18/Graduation, and which statute applies? Bushell v. Schepp may help.

I would strongly urge you to show this to a real lawyer in your juristiction.
Because yes, "until" means what it says in the dictionary.
*However, the whole sentence is a logcial mess. Whoever wrote it has no business writing contracts.
A good sentence would read "until child is 18 years of age and no longer enrolled in high school" or the other way round "while the child is a minor or still enrolled in highschool". And I am sure a professional lawyer could make it great, by applying their skills and not just logical reasoning and grammar rules.
Why? You pay child support until they graduated high school? As far as I know, that is not mandatory. Right now, that child could drop out of high school and found a garage company, get filthy rich, make billions, and when they fly a rocket to space at the age of 50, because they are so bored they don't know what else to do with their billions, you will still owe child support.
Take that sentence to someone who knows how to write a contract. Preferably a professional in your region.

Understood, but unfortunately, I wrote that into my divorce agreement.  However, the intent is to stop support payments at those points.  Missouri does extend support past those points and up to age 21  if enrolled in college.  So, it was written to avoid that.  Thank you for your comment.

Maybe your actual question is whether this sentence is valid in Missouri or superseded or voided by local law? Because you did not say this is in Missouri or even the US. We have no idea of any context. If you have this context, especially if it is needed to understand your question, please add it to your question.

IANAL, but is it possible that a court would rule that everyone understood that "graduated high school" was intended to mean "stopped going to high school". The "whichever is later" clause deals with dropping out before they reach graduatation age.

@Barmar - you can stop going to high school without graduating, otherwise known as dropping out. A poorly worded provision (I would have phrased it 'whichever comes first' at the least).

@JonCuster That's my point -- it's unlikely they really wanted to conditionalize it on the child successfully graduating. And the point of "comes last" is that if they drop out, the child support still stops at 18, so they can't drop out to keep support coming indefinitely.

Is it valid in Missouri?  I have two statutes that appear to contradict.  452.340 subsection 5 states in essence, if they are enrolled in secondary school support continues until 21.  However, 452.370 subsection 4 states support is terminated at emancipation unless agreed to in writing or expressly provided in the decree.  My decree provides the statement in my question, "Child support continues until age 18 or high school graduation.  Whichever is later."  My confusion is if that statement is enough to terminate at 18/Graduation, and which statute applies?  Bushell v. Schepp may help.

I believe 452.370 applies for the courts consideration regarding a motion to terminate support, which I have already started.

Please edit all this into your question, people reading only the question still have no idea what your actual problem or context is.

Emancipation is separate from simply turning 18, it's an entire legal proceeding in itself.
